# Why does Integer.parseInt() remove 0 from string values?

Tags: java, string, integer

I have been trying to investigate why `Integer.parseInt()` removes 0 and returns the remaining numbers. For example:

```
@Test
public void testInteger() {
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("01234"));
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("12340"));
}
```

The first line prints 1234 and the second 12340. Why is the 0 removed from the first line. This does not make sense. I am aware a Integer is the wrapper object of an int and an int stores 32 bits.

Could you please explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using the string "01234" as an integer (with `parseInt()`), the `system.out.println` is printing an integer.

"01234" as an integer would be 1234.  This is because 0 is the only integer that starts with a zero.

*None of these are real numbers:*

```
0456,
0234, 
05555555, 
01
```

If you were to store "01234" as a string, the 0 would hold its value.

Answer (score 0):

The zero in the first expression, once converted to an integer, is simply not significant.

If it were, what would be the difference between `01` and `001`? Why the conversion should ends with one non significant `0` as a right choice, even better than the one having two significant zeros? What about three significant zeros? According with this logic, it would have been even more significant!!

No, I'm sorry, figures that are not significant are removed, and that's why the string `'01234'` (that is, of course, a legal string) is converted to the integer `1234`.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) for further details:

> Leading zeros are never significant.

Comment: In many languages (even Java) a leading zero is very significant, a leading zero means the number is an octal (0123 = 83)

Answer (score 0):

Because integers do not begin with zero, zero has no importance in numbers integers then when parse `Integer.parseInt("01234")`, from string to int the 0 be  deleted `1234`.
Conversely where zero is at the end is not deleted `12340`.